# Android Building From Source error: could not load boot.img

Tags: android, android-source

I have followed the instuctions as posted on http://source.android.com/source/index.html to build an Android Source Environment. I am using Ubuntu 10.04. The process went without problems. After hours of downloading the Source Tree (I Have tried several including 2.1 and 4.0.1) and execution of the make command all image files were created in the directory '/WORKING_DIRECTORY/out/target/product/generic' except the boot.img file. I read across the internet that it is possible to create an own boot.img file using 'mkbootimg'. However I would like to avoid this in first place and use this option only as a last resort, because I am not familiar with the process as it requires some header files I am not certain of where to find them. I am curios why the boot.img file was not created.

Is somebody facing the same issue or maybe has solved the issue?

Best Regards

Comment: i don't get boot.img file after building ICS, check here my que.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/13578032/1855493

Answer (score 1):

You've built your image for an emulator. Thus, you not need an boot.img to run an emulator and that's why it is not in your directory. You should make build for a particular device. If this device is Google device you'll have no problems - just follow the instructions on the webpage: http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html

Comment: I already had word with a Google representative. He told me the same. As I develp for a Motorola Milestone this thing does not work.

Comment: Then, I do not understand your question. What do you want?

Comment: Maybe "in the meantime" is a better expression.